# How to open up this ceiling lightbulb cover?

Tags: recessed-lighting

Here is the ceiling of my kitchen. I need to replace a bulb behind this cover. I've tried pushing it up and twisting but nothing moves. How can I open this cover up?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to get a sense of scale from the pictures, but that looks like the sort of thing where the trim ring pulls down (a "can light") if the size is roughly 4-6" (100-150mm) diameter. They are usually held in by spring clips.

Comment: Yes, that's roughly the size. Sorry, how exactly does one open the cover and clips?

Comment: There are variations, but normally you pull straight down on the outer ring, and the whole thing drops 3 inches or so and stops. Then you can squeeze the springs to fully release one or both sides completely for more access if needed.